# Microcontroller and processor same thing or not?

Tags: microcontroller, processor

Is it correct to refer to a microcontroller as processor?

I know microcontroller is different than microprocessor. But is it the same as processor?

The whole point of this question is to verify if there is a difference  between these two "definitions": microprocessor and processor core.

Comment: Did you try to google? Or search in this forum?

Comment: I did, it's all about the difference between micro controller and microprocessor

Comment: OK. And what exactly do you mean by word "processor"?

Comment: Process the computer programming codes

Comment: I think the terms are used with very little attention to whatever distinction may exist between them. I think "processor" is kind of a general term for anything that fetches instructions and executes them. It could include a desktop CPU, or a mobile phone microprocessor or an embedded microcontroller.

Comment: Your question is the same as asking what is the difference between apple and fruit.

Comment: "I know microcontroller is different than microprocessor. But is it the same as processor" lol. You just said they are different, so...

Comment: I was wondering if there is a difference between microprocessor and processor . Happy to made you laugh but it is good to encourage conceptual questions rather than ridicule them without anything instructive to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller)

> A microcontroller (or MCU, short for microcontroller unit) is a small
>   computer on a single integrated circuit **containing a processor
>   core**, memory, and programmable input/output peripherals.

Answer (score 2):

- A processor processes computer instructions.
- A microprocessor is a very small (micro) processor, using a single chip to store all the transistors to process computer instructions.
- The [MegaProcessor](http://www.megaprocessor.com/) is a very large (mega) processor, that uses multiple 1m x 2m stands to hold individual transistors to, together, process computer instructions.
- A microcontroller is a very small (micro) processor, that processes computer instructions but also has a number of pins dedicated for controlling and sampling peripherals. It could have any number of the following:

  - General Purpose Input pins (with or without pullups);
  - General Purpose Output pins (with or without tristate capability);
  - General Purpose Input/Output [GPIO] pins - a combination of the above two;
  - Analog input pins, using Analog-to-Digital Converters [ADCs];
  - Analog output pins, using Digital-to-Analog Converters [DACs];
  - Pulse Width Modulation output pins, using inbuilt timers;
  - Universal Asyncrhronous Receiver/Transmitters [UARTs], for serial communications;
  - Universal Synchronous/Asyncrhronous Receiver/Transmitters [USARTs], for serial communications;
  - Serial Peripheral Interconnect [SPI] pins;
  - Inter-Integrated Circuit [IIC, I2C, I²C] pins;
  - Internal timers;
  - Internal Read Only Memory [ROM];
  - Internal Random Access Memory [RAM];
  - Internal Flash memory;
  - Internal Electrically Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory [EEPROM];

So a microcontroller is a microprocessor plus other things.